# Not showing groups in front-end website but group present on data base buddypress wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have inserted wp_bp_groups by using $wpdp class. All fields gets inserted but the groups I have inserted are not shown in the website. Only those groups are shown that are created using website interface. Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BuddyPress functions for BuddyPress operations. 
In this case, use  `groups_create_group( $args )` 
located in `buddypress\bp-groups\bp-groups-functions.php`

The groups you inserted directly probably don't have any members - so they don't show up. 
Use the function above to create groups and you won't have that problem.

Comment: hi, as soon as I update status in group it will appear. How can I use this function to insert directly on database? It would be great help from your side.

Comment: It doesn't insert 'directly'. Why would you want to? It creates the group and group meta that you need and makes those inserts. Take a look at the function. If you know how to use $wpdb, then it should be easy to use the function.

Comment: Please will you provide some info how to use $wpdb with this function. I am using $wpdb to directly insert post values in database.

Comment: Don't use $wpdb with the function. Use the function.

Comment: how I use buddypress function from external php page. please help me.

Comment: Got working using groups_create_group function without using $wpdb to insert directly.